# How to expand children ( multi level ) with FieldValues with OData

Tags: odata

Trying to $expand multiple levels of an item's children.
I have tried queries with `//*` at the end, but that didn't work, for example:
`/sitecore/api/ssc/aggregate/content/Items('/sitecore/content/Site/Editorials//*')`

That didn't work, as I kept getting errors like : 

`A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (*)`

Comment: Hi Jay! Welcome to SSE!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turns out we can use multiple levels of `$expand`, or even supply `$level` of depth,

https://github.com/object/Simple.OData.Client/issues/85

However, `$level` doesn't seem to allow expanding `FieldValues` for all levels, so I ended up having multiple `$expand` like so :

`/sitecore/api/ssc/aggregate/content/Items('/sitecore/content/MySite/MyContent')/Children?$expand=Children($expand=Children, FieldValues), FieldValues`